# APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY​ (uploading users' Email Account information)

Tags: android, google-play-console

Publishing status: Rejected
Your app has not been accepted into Google Play. This does not affect your existing app’s status on Google Play

**Your app is uploading users' Email Account information to example.com without posting a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Developer Console and from within the Play distributed app itself.**

I already have added app privacy policy in google play console, also in app where users can read and agree before sign up. How do I fix that issue?

Solved: Problem solved after adding policy checkbox in the app sign up page.

Comment: We have the same problem with you, but I can't find "policy checkbox in the app sign up page" as you mentioned. Could you show me the exact name of this section?

Comment: Solved this yet?

Answer (score 2):

Translate the privacy policy into English, even if your primary audience isn't English speaking. Place the translation alongside.

Worked for me.